# Can't we copy shape(s) from a PPT slide to word document in the orginal format in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I tried to copy autoshape from PPT to word. but its copying as picture format. We cant edit the text or shape in word. How to avoid this?

Code I m using not giving expected esult:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
{
   if (targetDoc != null)
   {
      shape.Copy();
      this.wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
   }
 }
```

Comment: you're obviously using something other than Word 2010, where this isn't an issue. But Word 2007 and Word 97-2003 are different in the way they handle AutoShapes, especially cross-product - which one are you using?

Comment: MSOffice 2007, VS 2008, Windows XP. My problem is, I can copy the shapes in picture format but not in 'autoshape' format

Comment: Got it. MS Word 2007 doesn't natively create or allow editing of PowerPoint/Excel 2007 AutoShapes (Word 2010 does). Word 2007 continues to use the version of AutoShapes used in Word 2003 and before - it's said that this is for some compatibility issues. To see for yourself, create a "heart" shape in both Word 2007 and in PowerPoint 2007 separately. You'll notice they look slightly different. Unfortunately, for what you're asking, it is not possible to copy from a PowerPoint 2007 and edit in Word 2007 as an editable AutoShape.

Comment: ok Thanks. But I can copy in EMF format which allows to edit points but not text inside the picture. How to enable edit picture option after pasting the emf picture? Any suggetion could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To do that, once you've copied over an EMF, just right-click on the EMF and choose "Grouping->Ungroup". You will now have access to the various components of the shape.

Answer (score 2):

somewhat i manged to copy shape in EMF format.

```
shape.Copy(); 

object objectMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;                                                                             
object objLink = false;
object objType = WdPasteDataType.wdPasteEnhancedMetafile;                                        
wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial(ref objectMissing, ref objLink, ref objectMissing, ref objectMissing, ref objType, ref objectMissing, ref objectMissing);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a default thing in the Office.Interop library which cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, Copy is not the right API

CopySepcial might be what you need (though you'll have to look at docs yourself)

**I suggest** recording a macro in Word, while you insert a single simple shape. Inspect the code generated in the macro and mirror *that* for building up the shapes as *shapes* in the target document.