# How to enable "edit picture" option in MS Word?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, presentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't we copy shape(s) from a PPT slide to word document in the orginal format in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787541/cant-we-copy-shapes-from-a-ppt-slide-to-word-document-in-the-orginal-format-in)

When I paste a autoshape from Presentation to MS word, it will convert as picture. ANybody has solution for this problem? Like, I want autohape should copy with its original format.
thanks a lot.

Comment: You say "programatically pasting" can you expand are use using interop, send keys or something a third party component?

Comment: My program is pasting a shape from PPT to word. And there is no way to paste shape from PPT to word in its original format so I am pasting it in EMF format. After that if I want edit picture, this "edit picture" option is disabled.  I am using C#, interop assemblies(12.0), MS office 2007.

Comment: You've already asked this question several times. See my answer in the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787541/cant-we-copy-shapes-from-a-ppt-slide-to-word-document-in-the-orginal-format-in